# How to load known host key from String instead of filesystem?

Tags: apache-sshd, known-hosts

I have a Spring Boot application with [Apache SSHD](https://mina.apache.org/sshd-project/).  Therefore, the application needs a [known host key](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/host-key#known-host-keys). How to provide this known host key?

For production I can use a static `known_hosts` file, but for integration test I need a dynamically generated known host key, because the port of the SSH server is not static and SSH doesn't support portless known host keys, see [SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS FILE FORMAT](http://man.openbsd.org/sshd.8#SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_FILE_FORMAT).

**Known hosts file**

```
[localhost]:2222 ssh-rsa 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
```

**Documentation**

In the documentation is listed an implementation for known host keys saved in the filesystem and an implementation for one static server key, see [`ServerKeyVerifier`](https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd/blob/master/docs/client-setup.md#serverkeyverifier):

> **`ServerKeyVerifier`**
>
> `client.setServerKeyVerifier(...);` sets up the server key verifier. As part of the SSH connection initialization protocol, the server proves its "identity" by presenting a public key. The client can examine the key (e.g., present it to the user via some UI) and decide whether to trust the server and continue with the connection setup. By default the client is initialized with an `AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier` that simply logs a warning that an un-verified server key was accepted. There are other out-of-the-box verifiers available in the code:
>
> - `RejectAllServerKeyVerifier` - rejects all server key - usually used in tests or as a fallback verifier if none of it predecesors validated the server key
> - `RequiredServerKeyVerifier` - accepts only one specific server key (similar to certificate pinning for SSL)
> - `KnownHostsServerKeyVerifier` - uses the known_hosts file to validate the server key. One can use this class + some existing code to update the file when new servers are detected and their keys are accepted.

But I couldn't find an example for `RequiredServerKeyVerifier`.

**Research**

I could disable server key validation in my integration tests, but I want to test the configuration code for server key validation, too.

I could dynamically change the `known_hosts` file in filesystem to change the port, but that is error prune and it increases the complexity (file permissions, parallel access).

**Question**

How to load known host key from `String` instead of filesystem?

Comment: Any update for the solution?